# Delete entire row if not even one cell is red or blue

Tags: vba, excel, loops

My macro is provided below. I want to delete all the rows, in which not even one cell is blue or red! So, the macro performs some coloring in the beginning, which works great! But, when I want to just keep the rows that have the colored cells, it does not work correctly. The macro does not tell me that it has an error. It just runs but never stops running :p Any ideas? Much appreciated!

```
Sub PO()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Worksheets("Tracker").Cells.Copy
    With Worksheets("po")
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlValues
    .Cells.PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With

    Sheets("po").Select

    Dim mDiff1 As Double
    mDiff1 = 0.01
    Dim mDiff2 As Double
    mDiff2 = 0.03
    Dim mDiff3 As Double
    mDiff3 = 0.01
    Dim mDiff4 As Double
    mDiff4 = 0.03

    For Each cell1 In Range(Range("U2"), Range("U2").End(xlDown))
    If cell1.Value - cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value > mDiff1 Then
    cell1.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
    If cell1.Value - cell1.Offset(0, 2).Value > mDiff2 Then
    cell1.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    End If
    Next cell1

    For Each cell2 In Range(Range("AB2"), Range("AB2").End(xlDown))
    If cell2.Value - cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value > mDiff3 Then
    cell2.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
    If cell2.Value - cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value > mDiff4 Then
    cell2.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    End If
    Next cell2

    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell3 As Range

    For Each row In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Rows
    For Each cell3 In row.Cells
    If Not cell3.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Or cell3.Interior.ColorIndex = 5 Then
    cell3.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next cell3
    Next row

    Sheets("po").Select
    If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows(1).AutoFilter
    End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Always work from bottom to top when deleting rows.

Comment: so how should I change it?

Comment: Change the loop from a `For Each` to a `For i = lastRow to 1 Step -1`. Google around and you'll find many examples of how to find the last row. Then it's `Cells(i,1).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: It got totally messed :p It has errors everywhere

Comment: copy the code that you posted above and try doing changes again. use F8 to single-step code.

Answer (score 4):

Try it like,

```
Dim i As Long, lr As Long, nodel As Boolean
Dim mDiff1 As Double, mDiff2 As Double, mDiff3 As Double, mDiff4 As Double

mDiff1 = 0.01
mDiff2 = 0.03
mDiff3 = 0.01
mDiff4 = 0.03

With Worksheets("po")
    lr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row, _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row)
    For i = lr To 2 Step -1
        nodel = False
        If .Cells(i, "U").Value2 - .Cells(i, "U").Offset(0, 1).Value2 > mDiff1 Then
            .Cells(i, "U").Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            nodel = True
        End If
        If .Cells(i, "U").Value2 - .Cells(i, "U").Offset(0, 2).Value2 > mDiff2 Then
            .Cells(i, "U").Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
            nodel = True
        End If
        If .Cells(i, "AB").Value2 - .Cells(i, "AB").Offset(0, 1).Value2 > mDiff3 Then
            .Cells(i, "AB").Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            nodel = True
        End If
        If .Cells(i, "AB").Value2 - .Cells(i, "AB").Offset(0, 2).Value2 > mDiff4 Then
            .Cells(i, "AB").Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
            nodel = True
        End If
        If Not nodel Then
           .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: well Jeeped you must be some type of a guru or something because it worked like a charm!!!!!  Thank you man!! However I want to ask you something, as I have been trying to find it for a long time... How did you manage to use the For each cell type of function for two different cells at the same time... also, what does this nodel do... and finally lr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row, _
                         .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row)   what does this do?? sorry for asking but I really want to learn!

Comment: 1. I didn't use a For Each, I used a For Next backwards from the bottom row number to the second row. 2. The maximum bottom row number of columns U & AB.

Comment: and the nodel ?

Comment: for each cycle of the for next, nodel starts as false. if any of the cell coloring occurs, then nodel is true. at the end of the cycle, if nodel is false (i.e. no cell coloring has occurred on that row) then delete row.

Comment: well thank you man !! and for the explanation and for everything!